# React Bootstrap Card Result in Multiple Columns

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Below is my code, my problem is, the results are displaying at the bottom one by one like this:

```
1
2
3
```

I want to display each output result as follows? as 3 column

```
1        2        3
4        5        so on......
```

I have used https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/ component to display the database output

```
{Mylist.length && Mylist.map((item, index) => {
                                    return (                                    
                                        <Card key={index} style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                                            <Card.Body>  
                                                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{moment(item.date_time).format('LLL')}</Card.Subtitle>                                 
                                                <Card.Text>{item.content}</Card.Text>
                                                <Button variant="danger" size="sm" data-id={item.id} onClick={() => remove(item.id)} >Delete</Button>{' '}                                            
                                            </Card.Body>
                                            </Card>
                                    )
                                })}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach, see more at https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/cards/#card-groups

```
  <Row xs={1} md={2} className="g-3">
        {Mylist.length && Mylist.map((item, index) => {
                                            return (
                                              <Col key={index}>
                                                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                                                    <Card.Body>  
                                                        <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{moment(item.date_time).format('LLL')}</Card.Subtitle>                                 
                                                        <Card.Text>{item.content}</Card.Text>
                                                        <Button variant="danger" size="sm" data-id={item.id} onClick={() => remove(item.id)} >Delete</Button>{' '}                                            
                                                    </Card.Body>
                                                    </Card>
                                                  </Col>
                                            )
                                        })} 
        </Row>
```

Comment: Perfect Answer! Thank you anthony_718